# ERROR/ActivityManager(60) has anyone encountered this on Android Emulator?

Tags: android

Whenever I start the application it keeps force closing citing the log below. Is this a CPU overload issue or memory management issue? I really don't understand how to resolve this?
Any help is much appreciated.

I am running Eclipse v 3.5.2 and Android SDK 0.98 and AVD is Froyo (2.2)

DDMS Log

10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60): ANR in Test.Tooyoou
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60): Reason: Executing service Test.Tooyoou/.TooyoouWidget$UpdateService
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60): Load: 1.17 / 0.68 / 0.26
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60): CPU usage from 20436ms to 33ms ago:
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):   adbd: 3% = 0% user + 3% kernel / faults: 10 minor
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):   Test.Tooyoou: 2% = 2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 197 minor 4 major
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):   system_server: 2% = 1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 134 minor 2 major
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):   ndroid.settings: 1% = 1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3016 minor 12 major
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):   ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 32 minor
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 174 minor
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):   ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 99 minor
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):   d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 22 minor
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):   netd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 64 minor 1 major
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):   com.svox.pico: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 26 minor
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):  +sh: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60):  +logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
10-10 23:53:53.379: ERROR/ActivityManager(60): TOTAL: 11% = 5% user + 4% kernel + 0% irq + 0% softirq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK folks I think I solved the problem behind this very ugly error. There was some issue with the BroadcastReceiver TimeOut and the Update service for the widget taking too long. Here I how I solved it.

Instead of doing everything using the Service for the AppWidget, I spawned a thread to do all the critical update work.

```
public static class UpdateService extends Service {
        Thread widgetUpdateThread;
        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        widgetUpdateThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                RemoteViews updateViews =   
                                       buildUpdate(getApplicationContext());
                            ComponentName thisWidget = new 
                              ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
                                                       TooyoouWidget.class);
                AppWidgetManager manager =  
                      AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                      manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);

            }
        };
        widgetUpdateThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        widgetUpdateThread.interrupt();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

     public RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context) {
     //your code to create the Remoteviews update
```

}

}

Once I used the Thread, everything works like a charm and that ugly error is gone. May be this will be helpful for some of you guys.